# What is the standard way to move docker volume around servers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have a docker volume defined in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "2"
services:
  postgres:
    image: my_image/postgresql:9.3
    volumes:
      - test_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  test_volume:
```

I want to know what is the standard way of backing up data from server?

Ideally I would like to just move docker volume around the servers, like from my production server to my sandbox server.

Or do people usually just dump the backup sql file and move it to somewhere else through automation tool?

Comment: `nfs`, `flocker` and etc. Also take a look at the [kubernetes way](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/).

Comment: [nfs example](http://netshare.containx.io/docs/nfs) and [flocker example](https://flocker-docs.clusterhq.com/en/latest/docker-integration/tutorial-swarm-compose.html)